# Mapping single table column to Complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to know if it is possible to map a single column from sql to a complex property on a model, Using EntityFramework.

Here is the code to better understand.

```
interface ISecret
{
 Guid EncryptedValue{get;set;}
 string DecryptedValue{get;set;      
}
```

In the database I might have a column for some type that has got something encrypted. I want to map this encrypted column to a property of type ISecret, so that my DecryptionService can just decrypt all the properties of ISecret.

I hope this possible and hope you understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think EF would be able to know which concrete type ISecret needs to map to. Would it not be a better solution if you mark the property with an Attribute specifying that the property is an encrypted value. Then you're DecryptionService could use reflection to decide which properties to decrypt

Comment: I was thinking of reflection, but people always warns against the performance impact